# Generating code for passing run-time boolean variables to template

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to generate code like

```
if (a && b)   do_something <true, true> (...);
if (a && !b)  do_something <true, false> (...);
if (!a && b)  do_something <false, true> (...);
if (!a && !b) do_something <false, false> (...);
```

using templates or preprocessor (number of boolean variables can be greater)?
I need to keep them as template arguments because of serious increase in performance caused by inlining but also want to avoid having a lot of code duplication.

Comment: Yes you can. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023384/transpose-template-function-boolean-arguments-to-runtime-function-arguments-with